# Register callback on Future

Tags: java, concurrency, ejb-3.1

I can write a method on an EJB like this, which will be run asynchronously:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import javax.ejb.AsyncResult;
import javax.ejb.Asynchronous;
...
@Asynchronous
public Future<String> foo(String s) {
    ...
    return new AsyncResult<String>("bar");
}
```

Is there a way to register a callback (e.g. a lambda) which will be called, once that Future is completed?  I don't want to block any threads by calling `Future#get()`.

Comment: The Guava library implements a `ListenableFuture` for exactly that purpose, along with a whole lot of related classes and utilities.

Comment: Is there a way to get an EJB to work with that?  I'm using Java 8 so I could use CompletableFuture but I can't work out how to get EJB to work with that.

Comment: No idea, I don't use EJB. You can convert a normal future, but not terribly efficiently. But there are other ways of converting code to use it that work better. See https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained